# How can I calculate probably approximate correct learning using Hoeffding's Inequality?

Tags: probability, self-study, probability-inequalities, mathematical-statistics

How can I calculate the required number of trials, N using the below Hoeffding's Inequality to obtain $\epsilon=0.1$ with 0.01% case?

Hoeffding's Inequality = $P(|\hat{\theta} - \theta^*|\geq\epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2N\epsilon^2}$